# How to export stand-alone HTML-CSS-JS from next-js to use in websites like github-pages

Tags: next.js

I have a simple `nextjs` application in next version 14.1.1. I tried to export my application into plain `html` format. But there is a problem. static contents like `css`, `js`, font, etc. files, have absolute address in exported html.

for example

```
/_next/static/media/c9a5bc6a7c948fb0-s.p.woff2
```

But I need to export them like

```
./_next/static/media/c9a5bc6a7c948fb0-s.p.woff2
```

or like this:

```
_next/static/media/c9a5bc6a7c948fb0-s.p.woff2
```

How can I change this?

**What I've tried**:

In `next.config.mjs` I added `assetPrefix:"./"` like:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output:'export',
    assetPrefix:"./",
};
 /* module.exports = nextConfig*/
export default nextConfig;
```

However, this led to the error message: `assetPrefix must start with a leading slash or be an absolute URL(http:// or https://)`.

Is there any straight-forward solution to export Next-js application as plain `html-css-js` format?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why do you need to have relative path? I assume they're making it absolute because in many applications you'll have routing that will manipulate URL, making relative URLs invalid.

Comment: @AlexanderBurov Yes. I actually need to use it in Github pages. absolute URLs not working in this case. look at https://sirsaleh.github.io/Portfolio/. If I manually change static URLs using browser inspect element styles will appears.

Comment: Try to upload to netlify

Comment: @SirSaleh you just need to provide it with a base path (absolute path to the root of your app). I think you just need to add `basePath: "/Portfolio",` to the `nextConfig`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem using absolute path for assetPrefix in in `.env` of production.

1. First of all I added an `.env` variable (here `assetPrefix`).

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

let assetPrefix = process.env.assetPrefix ? process.env.AssetPrefix : "";

const nextConfig = {
    output:'export',
    assetPrefix: assetPrefix,
  };

/* module.exports = nextConfig*/
export default nextConfig;
```

2. In github pages set the assetPrefix to the absolute path of my target website in env file. (here https://SirSaleh.github.io) **Note: Don't forget the `https` in the link.**

**Note**: Actually I used Github actions for automatic exporting the `nextjs` app to the plain `HTML, CSS, JS`  format. in my case to creating `.env` file I added this step to my action file before building:

```yaml
- name: 'Create env file'
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo AssetPrefix="https://${{ github.repository_owner }}.github.io/${{ github.event.repository.name }}/" >> .env
          cat .env
```

So the output of `.env` file will be (`AssetPrefix="SirSaleh.github.io/Portfolio/"`)

Answer (score 0):

Absolute URLs of the referenced static content are required to properly work in the applications with routing. Basic approach in such applications is following:

1. Configure web server in a way, so it will send back `index.html` for any request for non-existing file;
2. `index.html` references our react app;
3. Once called, our app checks the actual URL in the browser's address bar and renders appropriate components.

Now, lets imagine we have stylesheet reference in out `index.html` like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/styles.css" />`. And we have few pages on the `https://example.com`:

- `/` – our home page, for it stylesheet will resolve into `https://example.com/static/styles.css` and will be served successfully;
- `/products` – product list, for it styles URL will resolve into `https://example.com/products/static/styles.css` which does not exists;
- `/products/17` – detail page for product #17, again will resolve our URL into non-existing `https://example.com/products/17/static/styles.css`.

Based on the link you've shared in comment, you're publishing the app on the non-root path, so you have to configure [basePath](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/basePath), so it can generate correct absolute paths during the build:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output:'export',
    basePath:"/Profile",
};
 /* module.exports = nextConfig*/
export default nextConfig;
```